# How to call a method from other component to make onClick option working

Tags: reactjs

I have two components: Main and LeftMenu. There is an icon on the LeftMenu component. Desired functionality: clicking on icon will show/hide element from Main component.

I'm able to setup desired functionality working when adding FaDropbox icon into Main component. But when I'm trying to place it into LeftMenu component, it doesn't work.

Main component with FaDropbox icon working:

```
class Main extends Component {
  state = {
    isShowTiles: true
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Main">
        {/* Background color set with Helmet */}
        <Helmet>
          <style>{"body { background-color: #1A2C3B; }"}</style>
        </Helmet>
        <div className="Container">
          <Row className="RowHeader">
            <Header
              user={this.props.user}
              photo={this.props.photo}
              userProfile={this.props.userProfile}
            />
          </Row>
          <Row>
            <div class="toggleArea">
              {this.state.isShowTiles ? <Tiles /> : <BoxTiles />}
            </div>
          </Row>
        </div>
        <button onClick={this.toggleComponents}>
          <FaDropbox />
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }

  toggleComponents = () => {
    this.setState({
      isShowTiles: !this.state.isShowTiles
    });
  };
}

export default Main;
```

When I'm trying to call toggleComponents from LeftMenu component on FaDropbox icon, it doesn't work.

```
class LeftMenu extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="LeftMenu">
        {/* Base Layout */}
        <div className="LeftContainer">
          <Row className="justify-content-md-center">
            <div className="LeftIcon">
              {/* <FaDropbox/> */}
              <button onClick={toggleComponents}>
                <FaDropbox />
              </button>
            </div>
          </Row>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default LeftMenu;
```

I was trying to export toggleComponents method from Main component as below but it didn't work:

```
export function toggleComponents() {
  return this.toggleComponents;
}
```

The expected result is to make FaDropbox icon have onClick option working but on LeftMenu component. I don't want to have FaDropbox on the Main component. How to achieve this and correctly call this method from the outside of Main component?

Comment: where you are rendering LeftMenu component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the `toggleComponents` as props into LeftMenu.

`<LeftMenu toggleComponents = {this.toggleComponents}/>`

Then you can simply call it inside the LeftMenu like below

`<button onClick={() => this.props.toggleComponents()}><FaDropbox/></button>`

Answer (score 0):

Add a toggleComponents function to LeftMenu class and use it in the same way as in Main

```
<button onClick={this.toggleComponents}><FaDropbox/></button>
```

Remember about `this` binding in class:
https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

You can also pass `toggleComponents` function to `LeftMenu`

```
<LeftMenu toggleComponents={this.toggleComponents} />

class LeftMenu extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      ...
      <button onClick={this.props.toggleComponents}><FaDropbox/></button>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: How to pass this function to LeftMenu class? There is no LeftMenu in the form like <LeftMenu /> ...

Comment: You need to display somewhere `LeftMenu` One way is to use it like HTML tag <LeftMenu /> e.g. in your `Main` class. Or you can use so called `render props` technique: https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html

Comment: The thing is, I don't want to have LeftMenu in Main because it duplicates LeftMenu component... When added, I can see LeftMenu two times and the new instance of it in fact do the onClick job but this is not the expected result in general.

Comment: Then create a wrapper for both components e.g. `App` class with two components `LeftMenu` and `Main`, `toggleComponents` function can be passed down from the `App` (if I understand you correctly)

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide connections between two component. Like my though(minimalist version)

You have Layout Component

```
class Layout extends Component {
  state = {
    isShowTiles: true
  };
  toggleComponents = () => {
    this.setState({
      isShowTiles: !this.state.isShowTiles
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div class="layout">
        <Main isShowTiles={this.state.isShowTiles} />
        <LeftMenu toggleComponents={this.toggleComponents} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And in Main component:

```
class Main extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div class="toggleArea">
        {this.props.isShowTiles ? "Title" : "Box Title"}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And LeftMenu component:

```
class LeftMenu extends Component {
  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.props.toggleComponents}>Click me!</button>;
  }
}
```

Check out: https://codesandbox.io/s/943nkvzrno

Comment: Thanks, this one works for me. Now I'm thinking how to parametrize this, I mean, to use the same function but for other icon and decide what components show/hide.

Answer (score 0):

```
import LeftMenu from 'leftMenu';
class Main extends Component{
    state ={
        isShowTiles:true
    };

    toggleComponents=()=>{
        this.setState({
            isShowTiles:!this.state.isShowTiles
        })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Main">
                {/* Background color set with Helmet */}
                <Helmet>
                    <style>{'body { background-color: #1A2C3B; }'}</style>
                </Helmet>
                <div className="Container">
                    <Row className="RowHeader">
                        <Header user={this.props.user} photo={this.props.photo} userProfile={this.props.userProfile} />
                    </Row>
                    <Row>
                        <div class="toggleArea">
                            { this.state.isShowTiles ? <Tiles /> : <BoxTiles/> }
                        </div>
                    </Row>
                </div>
                <LeftMenu toggleComponents={this.toggleComponents} />
            </div> 
        );
    }
}

export default Main;
```

Left Menu component :

```
class LeftMenu extends Component {
    render() {
        const { toggleComponents } = this.props;
        return (
            <div className="LeftMenu">
                {/* Base Layout */}
                <div className="LeftContainer">
                    <Row className="justify-content-md-center">
                        <div  className="LeftIcon">
                        {/* <FaDropbox/> */}
                            <button onClick={toggleComponents}><FaDropbox/></button>
                        </div>
                    </Row>
                </div>
            </div> 
        );
    }
}
export default LeftMenu;
```

Comment: You should know state and props concepts in react.

Comment: The idea is not to have LeftMenu in Main component. <LeftMenu toggleComponents={this.toggleComponents} /> duplicates LeftMenu which is not needed.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your requirement...can you explain what do you want ?